# Wrap words with CSS in Selectbox Dropdown

Tags: css

I want to wrap the words that comes up in the drop-down Select box.

```
select#xyz option {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 11em;    
}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me

Comment: *Doesn't work* isn't an acceptable phrase to use to describe your issue. Do you have a live problem you can show or a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

In a standard `select` element, you can't wrap the items. You'd need a custom control.